# Windows IIS Forwarding domain.de to www.domain.de

Tags: windows, http, iis, https, server

before i start,  i tried the search bar and i saw posts but these didnt really help me.

So im currently trying to foward my domain to force HTTPS and www.

so like when i type mydomain.de it forwards me to https://www.mydomain.de

this is my web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="http to https secure" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?speargaming.de" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I dont see what i did wrong there.

Comment: // Fixed i forgot to Enable the Rule in the URL Rewrite module even tho it was enabled in the config.